# Angular Bootstrap ngbtimepicker Unable to set Model

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

In Angular 6 we are using Bootstrap ngbTimePicker facing the below error, Unable to set Model.

In the below code in timepicker.js

```
NgbTimepicker.prototype.changeHour = function (step) { this.model.changeHour(step);
```

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: Are you talk about https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples ? It's a "custom form control". You need feed using a [(ngModel)] (and a variable in your .ts) or a FormControl (if you use ReactiveForm)

Comment: Yes the same control, Its not an Reactive Form.                                                                     We are getting the error from the below code NgbTimepicker.prototype.changeHour = function (step) { this.model.changeHour(step);